# Destroy gameobject removes all object the script is attached to

Tags: unity-game-engine

provided I have following script

```c#
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Pickup : MonoBehaviour
{
    public RaycastHit Hit;
    public string PickupMessage = "none";

    private bool canHover;

    void Awake()
    {
        Debug.Log("This script is for " + gameObject.name);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Camera camera = Camera.main;
        Ray ray = camera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out Hit))
        {
            if (Hit.distance <= 1.5f && gameObject.tag == "pickup")
            {
                canHover = true;
                pickUpItem();
            }
            else
            {
                canHover = false;
            }
        }
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        if(canHover == true)
        {
            GUI.Box(new Rect((Screen.width / 2) - 100, (Screen.height / 2) - 100, 150, 20), PickupMessage.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void pickUpItem()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown("f"))
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

I have this script linked to two components (Key and Keyhole)

Yes when I am close to either one it will show both messages, similarly when I hit <kbd>F</kbd> near one of them, both get destroyed.

What am I missing that this is applied on both components that use this script?

Comment: Since each of these scripts cast their own ray, they are both detecting an object, and therefore making the Hit statement true in both scripts. Whether or not they are detecting the object that the script is attached to does not matter to them since they are just looking for any object that is tagged correctly and within the range. You should have a seperate object with the raycast logic to cast a single ray for object detection.

Comment: Yes! Thank you, that indeed works if I move the script to the player object. Does it make sense to switch the ray caster to the fps controller? How can I, then, make a custom message for the different objects?

Comment: the collision information for the ray is stored in the `Hit` component. so you could simply do... `print(Hit.collider.gameObject.name);` for example, or `Destroy(Hit.collider.gameObject);`. The raycaster should just be in a convenient location really.

Comment: Thank you! I will lock it to either the camera or the FP controller. If you'd post this as an answer I'd be able to accept this as resolved since this helped me a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that each of the scripts is casting their own ray. So, they are both being cast at the same point, detecting an object, and making the if-statement true. The rays in your script do not care what the object is since they are just looking for *any* object that is tagged correctly and within range, and not the object that the script is attached to.

What you should do instead is handle the raycasting in a separate object so that you are only casting a single ray for object detection.

While in a separate script, you can still interact with unique gameobjects since the collider information is stored in the Hit component.

```
if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out Hit))
{
    if (Hit.distance <= 1.5f && gameObject.tag == "pickup")
    {
        print(Hit.collider.gameObject.tag);
        Destroy(Hit.collider.gameObject);
    }
}
```